# How do I add a tooltip or overlay to a specific section of a chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, charts

I have a chart that displays several lines showing signal strengths over a frequency band.

Each chart is composed of one 'area' and four 'series'.  On the parent form there are several graphs like the one shown below.  All of them are created dynamically and will have different widths.

[image: Spectrum]

What I am trying to do is add a tooltip or annotation (or something) when the mouse hovers over a specific area of the chart as shown in the mockup below:

[image: Spectrum2]

If the mouse moved to the other side of the chart a different channel number and frequency would be shown in a box surrounding that area of the chart.

It doesn't have to be exactly as shown in the mockup although an outline would be preferred in order to show the user how wide the channel is regardless of the waveform shown in that area at the time.  For example, the waveform shown above might only be 8MHz wide but channel 1 itself might have an allocation that is 10MHz wide (the device varies its bandwidth based on its offered load.)

The X axis is MHz and a channel is defined in terms of MHz so it would be ideal to define the outline in terms of the X axis instead of pixels.

Also, note that this is a realtime chart that is updated up to 10 times per second.  Therefore it would be best if the information was not required to be updated each time new data arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to combine a couple of items to make the following solution:
[image]

[credit LICEcap]

The highlight is a rectangle filled in the 'OnPaint' method of the chart control.

The text is a simple TextAnnotation that is applied during the mousemove event.

It took quite a bit of coordinate conversion to get all the pieces in the right spot - especially the text.  I needed to convert between pixels, position and value.

The first conversion was to pixels in order to center the text using MeasureString.  I then converted it from pixel location to X axis value and then needed to convert it to position since the annotation requires using 'position' coordinates.  There is not a function to convert from pixels to position.  There is a pixels to value and a value to position which is the way I went.

I don't claim this to be the best or even a proper way to do it but it works.  If anyone else has a better solution or a way to improve my code please post.

Here's my code for positioning the text:

```
double temp = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(Convert.ToDouble(ce.sChannelFrequency) * 1000);
using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1))) {
    SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(freq.Text, new Font("eurostile", 13, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel));
    temp -= (size.Width/2+10);
}
if (temp < 0) temp = 0;
temp = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(temp);
freq.X = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPosition(temp);
```